# Northwind database for SQL Server CE?

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-6.5, northwind

Is there somewhere I can get a version of the Northwind database for SQL Server CE to run on Windows Mobile 6.5 (and below) devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my PC it's here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Samples`